High dimensional regression with millions of covariates/features
as a matter of preamble, I am a machine learning researcher. I am interested if this community can point me to research and work showing settings that have performed regression where the number of covariates is greater than 1 million?
I am familiar with LASSO, Ridge, and even other solvers in high dimensional regression. However, I haven't seen/come across any paper that demonstrates effectiveness of a solver at the million of features level.
To be more specific, here is what I mean: $$Y = X\theta$$, where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ is a matrix with $n$ samples and $p$ features. I am asking about solvers for the $p\ge 1,000,000$ case. Also, assume that $p\ge n$, so it is the underdetermined case.
if you have experience in this area, feel free to share references to papers and code that are applicable. Thank you.

Genome-wide association studies are one example. They are special because the models are quite sparse and because strong correlation between predictors is limited to genetic variants that are physically nearby on a chromosome.

Zhu & Stephens discuss Bayesian regresion at roughly 2.5 million predictors

A large group here uses half a million predictors and several to 50 $Y$ variables



Thanks for the references, these are quite helpful. I'll check them out!
